# Does access granted via Case Team Members roll up via the Role Hierarchy? If so, why?

Tags: case, sharing, role-hierarchy, case-teams

I've done some testing on this and would like someone to confirm that it is expected behaviour that adding a User to a Case Team results in Users above them in the role hierarchy being able to gain access to the Case record.

#### Secnario:

We are using Cases with a Private OWD and opening up access via sharing rules + role hierarchy. We want to use Case Teams to allow users to collaborate with other team members, adding them either as a Viewer or Collaborator role. However, if someone adds a User to the Case Team, it seems as though Users above them in the Hierarchy also get granted access to the case.

**Is this expected?** And if so, why?? Records shared via Manual Sharing are not rolled up via the Role Hierarchy, and Case Teams feels very similar to Manual Sharing, with the difference that you can define roles and pre-define teams of Users to add. Are Case Teams just built differently and intended to work with the role hierarchy?

**And lastly (long shot)...** I know that there is no way to deactivate "Grant Access via Hierarchies" for standard objects like Case, but is there any way to disable granting access via the hierarchy specifically for Case Team Members?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Submitted a Case with Salesforce Support and they confirmed this is expected behaviour and there is no way to prevent Case Team Member access from being rolled up via the Role Hierarchy.